# Java Script Calculating and Displaying Idle Time

Tags: javascript, html, time, mousemove

I'm trying to write with javascript and html how to display the time a user is idle (not moving mouse or pressing keys). While the program can detect mousemovements and key presses, the program for some reason isn't calling the idleTime() method which displays the time in minutes and seconds.

I'm wondering why the method isn't getting called, as if it is called it would display true or false if a button is pressed.

```
var startIdle = new Date().getTime();
var mouseMoved = false;
var buttonPressed = false;

function idleTime() {
  document.write(buttonPressed);
  if (mouseMoved || buttonPressed) {
  startIdle = new Date().getTime();
  }
  document.getElementById('idle').innerHTML =   calculateMin(startIdle) + " minutes: " + calculateSec(startIdle)   + " seconds";
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
  idleTime()
  }, 500);
}

function calculateSec(startIdle1) {
  var currentIdle = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentIdle - startIdle1);
  var idleSec = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000));
  return idleSec % 60;
}

function calculateMin(startIdle1) {
  var currentIdle = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentIdle - startIdle1);
  var idleMin = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 60));
  return idleMin;
}

var timer;

// mousemove code
var stoppedElement = document.getElementById("stopped");

function mouseStopped() { // the actual function that is called
   mouseMoved = false;
   stoppedElement.innerHTML = "Mouse stopped";
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
   mouseMoved = true;
   stoppedElement.innerHTML = "Mouse moving";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(mouseStopped, 300);
});

//keypress code
var keysElement = document.getElementById('keyPressed');

window.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   buttonPressed = false;
   keysElement.innerHTML = "Keys not Pressed";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout("keysPressed", 300);
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
   buttonPressed = true;
   keysElement.innerHTML = "Keys Pressed";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout("keyPressed", 300);

});

function checkTime(i) {
   if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i
   }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
   return i;
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body onload="idleTime()">


    <div id="stopped"><br>Mouse stopped</br></div>
    <div id="keyPressed"> Keys not Pressed</div>

    <strong>
      <div id="header"><br>Time Idle:</br>
      </div>
    <div id="idle"></div>


    </strong>
  </body>
```

Comment: `document.write` probably doesn't do what you expect it to do, so just avoid using it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the keysElement and stoppedElement were not referred firing before the DOM load. and also removed the document.write

Thats all all good. :)

```js
var startIdle = new Date().getTime();
var mouseMoved = false;
var buttonPressed = false;

function idleTime() {
  //document.write(buttonPressed);
  if (mouseMoved || buttonPressed) {
  startIdle = new Date().getTime();
  }
  document.getElementById('idle').innerHTML =   calculateMin(startIdle) + " minutes: " + calculateSec(startIdle)   + " seconds";
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
  idleTime()
  }, 500);
}

function calculateSec(startIdle1) {
  var currentIdle = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentIdle - startIdle1);
  var idleSec = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000));
  return idleSec % 60;
}

function calculateMin(startIdle1) {
  var currentIdle = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentIdle - startIdle1);
  var idleMin = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 60));
  return idleMin;
}

var timer;

// mousemove code
//var stoppedElement = document.getElementById("stopped");

function mouseStopped() { // the actual function that is called
   mouseMoved = false;
   document.getElementById("stopped").innerHTML = "Mouse stopped";
}

function keyStopped() { // the actual function that is called
   buttonPressed = false;
   document.getElementById("keyPressed").innerHTML = "Keys stopped";
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
   mouseMoved = true;
   document.getElementById("stopped").innerHTML = "Mouse moving";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(mouseStopped, 500);
});


window.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   buttonPressed = true;
   document.getElementById('keyPressed').innerHTML = "Keys Pressed";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(keyStopped, 500);
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
   buttonPressed = true;
   document.getElementById('keyPressed').innerHTML = "Keys Pressed";
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(keyStopped, 500);

});

function checkTime(i) {
   if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i
   }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
   return i;
}

window.onload = idleTime;
```

```html
<div id="stopped"><br>Mouse stopped</br></div>
<div id="keyPressed"> Keys not Pressed</div>
<strong>
  <div id="header"><br>Time Idle:</br></div>
  <div id="idle"></div>
</strong>
```

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for. Actually try wrapping up all your functions in one block/fn and then execute it on body load. that will make sure you have all what you wanted to

Comment: Thank you so much this did help. However, i'm not sure why whenever i push down a key or move the mouse, the timer is reset to 1 min 0 sec.

overall thanks for the help

Comment: Accept n up vote please. If u think it did work for u

Comment: i up voted but i am new so it hides my upvote. I still cannot figure out tho why the timer is reset to 1 min tho

Comment: on key press you mean ??

Comment: check out I have edited the answer now in the DOM when you do keypress  it will listen for a second. please accept an answer

Comment: i figured it out. for the math method, i rounded up (math.ceil) instead of down (math.floor). so now it is correctly saying 0 min upon refresh. Thanks for your help